# Is it possible to kill an electric eel in Crash Bandicoot 2: Cortex Strikes Back?

Tags: crash-bandicoot-n-sane-trilogy, crash-bandicoot-2

I've never liked the eels, but common sense would say that the only thing to do when encountering an electric eel is to avoid it. Ever since I first played the game I always thought the eels were invincible, and while reading from [Bandipedia](https://crashbandicoot.fandom.com/wiki/Bandipedia:Main_Page) (Fandom) on the [electric eel page](https://crashbandicoot.fandom.com/wiki/Electric_Eel), it seemed clear that the **Behavior** section confirmed by belief:

> They can't be defeated or interacted with at all.

However, as I continued reading I found that the same creature in one specific game (*[Crash Bandicoot: The Huge Adventure](https://crashbandicoot.fandom.com/wiki/Crash_Bandicoot:_The_Huge_Adventure)*) apparently *could* be killed:

> They can be defeated when no electrical charge goes though their bodies.

Given that electric eels could be killed in the other game, I'm wondering if perhaps there *is* some way to kill the electric eels in Crash 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they cannot be killed.

In the original trilogy, as well as the remaster, they cannot be interacted with.